# Mensaje personalizado con cuenta atrás en el comando TIMEOUT

Tags: cmd, batch

Básicamente lo que quiero es, en un archivo bat, cambiar el mensaje de salida del comando TIMEOUT para que en lugar de mostrar "presione una tecla para continuar ..." o con el parámetro /NOBREAK "presione CTRL+C para salir ..." muestre "presione una tecla para salir ..." pero con la cuenta atrás.

Es decir, de la siguiente manera puedo ponerle mi mensaje personalizado, pero los segundos permanecen estáticos:

```
TIMEOUT /T 60 > NUL | SET /P =Esperando 60 segundos, presione una tecla para salir ... & ECHO(
```

Lo que me gustaría es que los segundos hiciesen la cuenta atrás. Por el momento tengo una solución alternativa temporal que querría sustituir:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION  
FOR /F %%A IN ('COPY /Z "%~f0" NUL') DO SET "CR=%%A"  
FOR /L %%J IN (60 -1 1) DO (  
    < NUL SET /P =Esta ventana se cerrar  autom ticamente en %%J segundos !CR!  
    ping -n 2 localhost > NUL
)
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que puedas hacer nada diferente a lo que has hecho. Únicamente lo mejoraría utilizando el propio timeout en lugar de ping. Así funcionará aunque el PC no esté conectado a la red. Y la pausa además será más exacta.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%a in ('copy /z "%~f0" nul') do set "cr=%%a" 
for /l %%j in (10 -1 1) do (  
    <NUL set /P="Esta ventana se cerrar automaticamente en %%j segundos !CR!"
    timeout 1 /NOBREAK 1>NUL 2>&1
)
```